# Water damaged door casing repair

Tags: water-damage, door-frame

Our laundry room recently flooded with some water and the door casings have swelled at the very bottoms . They are MDF. I’m hoping to not have to remove them. Can I scrape the paint, sand and repaint? I’ve included pictures [image]

Answer (score 1):

The MDF has swelled and now is most likely mush, or dried mush ready to fall apart. The paint is holding it on.

You can get a wood chisel and try to shave off just what has been ruined by the water. Then fill it smooth with a hard setting filler like [Durhams Rock Hard](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Durham-s-Rock-Hard-DU-4-4-lb-Water-Putty-DU-4/202535298?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD-71700000110012104-58700008378060403-92700076247463880&gclid=CjwKCAjwm4ukBhAuEiwA0zQxk2ihdPEzpXncYYcLYzkcz-u8WRUHxXzzCrYEhwMhOsvPARnNuc8g9xoChkwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)  Then sand and paint.

```
              Or better
```

Cut out the damaged area and replace it with new wood.

```
            Or Best
```

Replace all the casing with finger jointed wood or even PVC molding, and you will not have an issue if there is flooding again.